Medspacy Scispacy compatibility issue
I am trying to use the en_ner_bionlp13cg_md model with medspacy. This only seems to work if I diable the parser, which is a major appeal of medspacy, as seen below:
nlp = medspacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md", disable=['parser'])

This is successful, but I lose parsing.
If I run the following:
nlp = medspacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md")
text = "blahblahblah"
doc = nlp(text)
visualize_ent(doc)

I get the following error:
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [86], in <cell line: 2>()
1 text = "blahblahblah"
----> 2 doc = nlp(text)
3 visualize_ent(doc)

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py:1054, in Language.call(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
1052 raise ValueError(Errors.E109.format(name=name)) from e
1053 except Exception as e:
-> 1054 error_handler(name, proc, [doc], e)
1055 if not isinstance(doc, Doc):
1056 raise ValueError(Errors.E005.format(name=name, returned_type=type(doc)))

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py:1722, in raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e)
1721 def raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e):
-> 1722 raise e

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py:1049, in Language.call(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
1047 error_handler = proc.get_error_handler()
1048 try:
-> 1049 doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {})) # type: ignore[call-arg]
1050 except KeyError as e:
1051 # This typically happens if a component is not initialized
1052 raise ValueError(Errors.E109.format(name=name)) from e

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyRuSH\PyRuSHSentencizer.py:53, in PyRuSHSentencizer.call(self, doc)
51 def call(self, doc):
52 tags = self.predict([doc])
---> 53 cset_annotations([doc], tags)
54 return doc

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyRuSH\StaticSentencizerFun.pyx:48, in PyRuSH.StaticSentencizerFun.cset_annotations()

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyRuSH\StaticSentencizerFun.pyx:56, in PyRuSH.StaticSentencizerFun.cset_annotations()

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\tokens\token.pyx:509, in spacy.tokens.token.Token.sent_start.set()

File c:\Users\ddefr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\tokens\token.pyx:528, in spacy.tokens.token.Token.is_sent_start.set()

ValueError: [E043] Refusing to write to token.sent_start if its document is parsed, because this may cause inconsistent state.

Any assistance in resolving this is greatly appreciated. I do not have this error if I use spacy.load(), only medspacy.load().

medspacy developer her.  This issue has been brought up previously here on our GitHub issues.
Note that scispacy and medspacy both have sentence boundary detection algorithms. You need to choose one of them both not both. Then you will not get this conflict.
Also, the reason this works without "parser" is that "parser" enables a sentence boundary method as a dependency.
More information here:
https://github.com/medspacy/medspacy/issues/131
The issue above should help you with what you need. If you disagree, feel free to re-open this ticket.
